# Replace instance method with rspec-mock

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec-mocks

[The RSpec documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-10/docs/configuring-responses/calling-the-original-implementation) shows how to mock a class method. How can I replace an instance method instead. Here is a code example using `rspec-mocks` to make this more concrete:

```
require 'rspec'

class Foo
  def foo
    "foo"
  end

  def foobar
    foo + "bar"
  end
end

RSpec.describe "Foo" do
  it "mocks foo" do
    allow(Foo).to receive(:foo).and_return("bar")
    foo = Foo.new
    expect(foo.foobar).to eq("barbar")
  end
end
```

This gives "Foo does not implement: foo". Granted, this is contrived for simplification. In the actual class I'm testing, `foo` makes a HTTP request, so I want to mock it while writing a spec for `foobar`. I'd like to do this with `rspec-mocks`, but if another gem can help here, I'm open to that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just stub the method on the instance instead of the class:

```
RSpec.describe "Foo" do
  it "mocks foo" do
    foo = Foo.new
    allow(foo).to receive(:foo).and_return("bar")
    expect(foo.foobar).to eq("barbar")
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had tried this in my actual project and it didn't work. Now it dawned on me that it's because I'm calling the equivalent of `foo` in my example here from `initialize`. So maybe I need to rethink the design of my class.